# Interactively manipulating a rectangle on a matlab figure

Tags: user-interface, matlab, interactive

I would like to draw and manipulate a rectangle on a matlab figure.  By manipulating, I mean I want to drag, rotate, resize (change side lengths) the rectange with "intuitive" mouse clicks.

I have not found any built in mechanism for doing this.  (Property editor?  Or matlab function?  Or matlab file exchange?)  Maybe I can't google well.

So, in order to write my own, it looks to me like the buttonDownFcn on the rectangle function is a start for this.  That is, I can use this to listen to mouse clicks on the rectangle itself, but what about mouseclicks on the inside of the rectangle?  I can't figure out how to receive them.  What about a "buttonUpFcn" don't see one of those.  What about when I move the cursor around, I see no way to capture those (unless I start querying the figure instead of the rectangle, but that gets to be a huge hassle, and very complicated I would think.)

Thanks for your consideration.

John

Comment: If you don't absolutely need rotation, `imrect` will do what you want.

Comment: @Jonas make this an answer, and I'll accept it.  impoly is sufficiently close to what I need, that that will work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't absolutely need rotation, [IMRECT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imrect.html) will do what you want. Also, if you need to be able to draw oblique lines, [IMPOLY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/impoly.html), could be helpful, though you may need to write a [POSITIONCONSTRAINFCN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imroi.html#imroi-setposcon) to guarantee that you're drawing right angles.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, this solves my immediate problem, and gives me a much lower effort path for longer term problems!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to store the location of the top-left and bottom-right rectangle corners and use those to determine whether clicks are inside or outside the rectangle. Those corners will give you the `[xmin ymin]` and `[xmax ymax]` values of the rectangle, and you can simply compare the location of the click to those values to determine whether the click is inside or outside the borders.